# MeegoTouch CSS Style Problem

Tags: css, qt, meego

I write a Meego App. But the CSS sytle not work normally. And I want to know how to get the CSS sytle works ? THX.

My Steps:

1. in .pro, add meegotouch lib
2. css file named style.css and I add a qrc file to reference the style.css
3. in Code, just load the css style.
   MTheme::loadCSS(":/style/style.css");

at the first time, the style works, but it fail to change the style when I re-write some attributes in the CSS file.
And I have to re-name the css file(maybe style1.css) and re-add in the qrc file, it will get work.

Any solution or did I miss something??

Comment: Can you supply a live link for us to see?

Comment: As a side-note, i should like to mention that the MeegoTouchFramework (libmtf) has been deprecated since October, and that you really ought to be not using it to develop new applications. As such, if you have not gotten too far ahead, i would strongly recommend switching over to using Qt Quick in stead (this is the officially recommended toolkit for MeeGo applications)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you included more code.

The only thing that I can think of is the simple problem of not reloading the application (or at least re-running the method where you load the css file) after you change the css file.

But I still don't know what you're doing.